# Get differences between 2 dataframes

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

In Python, I need to get differences between 2 dataframes having a different number of columns and rows.

A column "Pk" is present in both dataframes. The schemas are not known in advance.

The output should be a new dataframe containing **only** the rows and columns having diferent values.

For example:

`df_expected`

| pk | column1 | amount1 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | 11 | 101 |
| 2 | B | 12 | 102 |
| 3 | C | **13** | 103 |
| 4 | D | 14 | **104** |

`df_actual`:

| pk | column1 | extra_column | amount1 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | AA | 11 | 101 |
| 2 | B | BB | 12 | 102 |
| 3 | C | CC | **13.1** | 103 |
| 4 | D | DD | 14 | **104.1** |

`df_output` should be:

| pk | amount1 | amount2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 3 | Actual: 13.1, Expected: 13 |  |
| 4 |  | Actual: 104.1, Expected 104 |

Applied Rules:

- Rows 1 & 2 excluded as identical in both dataframes for common columns
- extra_column exluded as not present in first data frame
- column1 excluded as identical in both data frames

Comment: Could you give an example input and output to clarify? Do the two dataframes have the same number of rows, with PK acting as the primary key for joining?

Comment: Pk is acting as the primary for joining. @RufusBarnes

Comment: an example means posting the values of df1, the values of df2, what is the desired output and what code have you tried to get this result.

Comment: @RufusBarnes, added the sample

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, you are right, add am explanatory sample

Comment: But amount 1 and 2 are numbers right? If your resulting dataframe is the string "actual 13.1 expected 13" then you are changing the data type that this columns will store

Comment: Changing the column type is possible in the output dataframe. @SembeiNorimaki, propose anything similar.

Comment: Sorry I cannot see the logic. Where does the 104.1 come from? It's not in either of your dataframes. Also in the expected dataframe the value1 column has an expected value of 13 for the first row. But this 13 is only found in the column value2. I cannot find a logic on how the values are compared

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, 104.2 comes from last line of second dataframe. I put with bold the differences in both datasets.

Comment: So am I correct in thinking that the output should be a new data frame, with PK as the index, containing only data from shared columns where the cell value is different between the two data frames?

Comment: @RufusBarnes, yes, the output should be a new dataframe. Updated the question.

Comment: you just edited the dataframes, now they show different data than before.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses the pyspark library `pyspark-extension`. It allows to find differences of dataframes very easily. For distributed version, you will have to include the jar.

https://github.com/g-research/spark-extension

Requirements : `pip install pyspark-extension`

Code is as follows :

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark import SparkContext, SQLContext
from gresearch.spark.diff import *
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .config("spark.jars.packages", "uk.co.gresearch.spark:spark-extension_2.12:2.9.0-3.4") \
    .getOrCreate()

sc = spark.sparkContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

data1 = [
    [1, "A", "11", "101"],
    [2, "B", "12", "102"],
    [3, "C", "13", "103"],
    [4, "D", "14", "104"],

]
data1_schema = ["pk","column1","amount1","amount2"]
df1 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data1, schema=data1_schema)
print("df1 dataframe")
df1.show(truncate=False)




data2 = [
    [1, "A", "AA", "11", "101"],
    [2, "B", "BB", "12", "102"],
    [3, "C", "CC", "13.1", "103"],
    [4, "D", "DD", "14", "104.1"],

]
data2_schema = ["pk", "column1", "extra_column", "amount1", "amount2"]
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data=data2, schema = data2_schema)
print(" df2 dataframe")
df2.show(truncate=False)



df2 = df2.select(df1.columns)

options = DiffOptions().with_change_column("changes")
diff_result = df1.diff_with_options(df2, options, 'pk')


diff_result = diff_result.select("pk", "diff", "changes")
diff_result.show(truncate=False)


diff_result = diff_result.filter(F.col("diff") != "N")
diff_result.show(truncate=False)

changed_cols = ["amount1", "amount2"]

df1 = df1.withColumn("struct_cols", F.struct( [ele for ele in changed_cols]))
df2 = df2.withColumn("struct_cols", F.struct( [ele for ele in changed_cols]))

df1.show(truncate=False)
df2.show(truncate=False)



df1_new_cols = ["df1_"+col for col in df1.columns]
df2_new_cols = ["df2_"+col for col in df2.columns]

df1 = df1.toDF(*df1_new_cols)
df2 = df2.toDF(*df2_new_cols)


all_joined = diff_result.join(df1, diff_result["pk"] == df1["df1_pk"]).join(df2, diff_result["pk"] == df2["df2_pk"])

all_joined.show(truncate=False)

def list_values(col_names, df1_col_struct, df2_col_struct):
   list_all_values = [{"column_name": name, "Actual": df2_col_struct[name], "Expected": df1_col_struct[name]} for name in col_names]
   return list_all_values

list_values_udf = F.udf(list_values)


required_diff = all_joined.withColumn("all_changes", list_values_udf("changes", "df1_struct_cols", "df2_struct_cols"))

required_diff.show(truncate=False)

required_diff.select("pk", "all_changes").show(truncate=False)
```

Output is as follows :

```
df1 dataframe
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|pk |column1|amount1|amount2|
+---+-------+-------+-------+
|1  |A      |11     |101    |
|2  |B      |12     |102    |
|3  |C      |13     |103    |
|4  |D      |14     |104    |
+---+-------+-------+-------+

 df2 dataframe
+---+-------+------------+-------+-------+
|pk |column1|extra_column|amount1|amount2|
+---+-------+------------+-------+-------+
|1  |A      |AA          |11     |101    |
|2  |B      |BB          |12     |102    |
|3  |C      |CC          |13.1   |103    |
|4  |D      |DD          |14     |104.1  |
+---+-------+------------+-------+-------+

+---+----+---------+
|pk |diff|changes  |
+---+----+---------+
|1  |N   |[]       |
|2  |N   |[]       |
|3  |C   |[amount1]|
|4  |C   |[amount2]|
+---+----+---------+

+---+----+---------+
|pk |diff|changes  |
+---+----+---------+
|3  |C   |[amount1]|
|4  |C   |[amount2]|
+---+----+---------+

+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|pk |column1|amount1|amount2|struct_cols|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|1  |A      |11     |101    |{11, 101}  |
|2  |B      |12     |102    |{12, 102}  |
|3  |C      |13     |103    |{13, 103}  |
|4  |D      |14     |104    |{14, 104}  |
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+

+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|pk |column1|amount1|amount2|struct_cols|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+
|1  |A      |11     |101    |{11, 101}  |
|2  |B      |12     |102    |{12, 102}  |
|3  |C      |13.1   |103    |{13.1, 103}|
|4  |D      |14     |104.1  |{14, 104.1}|
+---+-------+-------+-------+-----------+

+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|pk |diff|changes  |df1_pk|df1_column1|df1_amount1|df1_amount2|df1_struct_cols|df2_pk|df2_column1|df2_amount1|df2_amount2|df2_struct_cols|
+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+
|3  |C   |[amount1]|3     |C          |13         |103        |{13, 103}      |3     |C          |13.1       |103        |{13.1, 103}    |
|4  |C   |[amount2]|4     |D          |14         |104        |{14, 104}      |4     |D          |14         |104.1      |{14, 104.1}    |
+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+

+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|pk |diff|changes  |df1_pk|df1_column1|df1_amount1|df1_amount2|df1_struct_cols|df2_pk|df2_column1|df2_amount1|df2_amount2|df2_struct_cols|all_changes                                        |
+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+
|3  |C   |[amount1]|3     |C          |13         |103        |{13, 103}      |3     |C          |13.1       |103        |{13.1, 103}    |[{column_name=amount1, Expected=13, Actual=13.1}]  |
|4  |C   |[amount2]|4     |D          |14         |104        |{14, 104}      |4     |D          |14         |104.1      |{14, 104.1}    |[{column_name=amount2, Expected=104, Actual=104.1}]|
+---+----+---------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+------+-----------+-----------+-----------+---------------+---------------------------------------------------+

+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|pk |all_changes                                        |
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
|3  |[{column_name=amount1, Expected=13, Actual=13.1}]  |
|4  |[{column_name=amount2, Expected=104, Actual=104.1}]|
+---+---------------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the answer, maybe someone else is having the same business need.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

def CompareData(df_expected, df_actual):

    # Find common columns between the two dataframes
    common_columns = list(set(df_expected.columns) & set(df_actual.columns))
    common_columns.remove('Pk')    

    # Prepare expected
    columns_to_rename = [col_name for col_name in df_expected.columns if col_name != 'Pk']
    for col_name in columns_to_rename:
        df_expected = df_expected.withColumnRenamed(col_name, col_name + '_expected')


    # Prepare actual
    columns_to_rename = [col_name for col_name in df_actual.columns if col_name != 'Pk']
    for col_name in columns_to_rename:
        df_actual = df_actual.withColumnRenamed(col_name, col_name + '_actual')


    # Perform the merge on the 'pk' column
    merged_df = df_expected.join(df_actual, on='Pk', how='inner')
    display(merged_df)
    all_columns = merged_df.columns
    print (f"All columns: {all_columns})")
    print(f"Common columns: {common_columns}")


    # Drop columns not common
    for col in all_columns:
        col2 = col.replace("_expected", "").replace("_actual", "")
        if col2 not in common_columns and col != "Pk":
            merged_df = merged_df.drop(col)
            print (f"Deleted [{col}] as not common")


    # Drop identical columns
    for column_name in common_columns:
        expected_column_name = column_name + "_expected"
        actual_column_name = column_name + "_actual"
        if merged_df.filter(F.col(expected_column_name) != F.col(actual_column_name)).count() == 0:        
            merged_df = merged_df.drop(expected_column_name)
            merged_df = merged_df.drop(actual_column_name)
            common_columns.remove(column_name)
            print (f"Deleted columns [{expected_column_name}], [{actual_column_name}] because values match.")

        
    # Update columns that have differences
    for column_name in common_columns:
        expected_column_name = column_name + "_expected"
        actual_column_name = column_name + "_actual"
        merged_df = merged_df.withColumn(
            column_name, 
            F.when(F.col(expected_column_name) != F.col(actual_column_name), 
                F.concat(F.lit('Actual: '), F.col(actual_column_name), F.lit(', Expected: '), F.col(expected_column_name)))
            .otherwise(""))    

    #Extract only needed columns
    result_df = merged_df[['Pk'] + common_columns]
    display(result_df)
```